# Jquery Form Validation Script Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsfiddle

I am just learning Jquery, and I am having an issue with the validation function when I add it to a loading script. When I use the validation function separately from the loading script, it works without error.

This fiddle has both the loading and validation functinon separated, and the validation works
http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/gzSDH/14/

This is the loading script I am trying to make work with the validation in it:

```
<script>
   var submit_hit = false;
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
      $('#loader1').hide();

      if(submit_hit){
          $('#form_container').hide();
          $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
          $('body').css("background-image", "url(images/previewbg.jpg)");
      }
  });

  $('#form_710370').submit(function(e){
      $('#loader1').show();
          submit_hit = true;
          return true;
      });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You don't nead document-ready event for these 2 other events.

```
var submit_hit = false;

$('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
   $('#loader1').hide();

   if (submit_hit) {
      $('#form_container').hide();
      $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
      $('body').css("background-image", "url(images/previewbg.jpg)");
   }
});

$('#form_710370').submit(function (e) {
   $('#loader1').show();
   submit_hit = true;
   return true;
});

$.validate();
$('#my-textarea').restrictLength($('#max-length-element'));
```

Comment: I just tried that, but the problem is the loading script starts the loading animation even if the validation is wrong. So I need them to work together.

Comment: The way you handled validation is not correct. Refer http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/